# using CSS to hide certain tr with specific class name only if it contain keyword

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many `tr`s which have the same class name - *sectiontableentry1*.
I want this `tr` to be hidden only if it contains a keyword, such as *"recommended"*.

Here is an example  http://jsfiddle.net/aQfQK/1/

Comment: Do you want to do this on the server-side (i.e. PHP) or client-side (i.e. JavaScript)? Is the HTML generated?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/css-3-content-selector - There's no CSS selector for content.  You'll have to use JS.

Comment: @timss the html is retrieved from remote site i want to do it on client side with jquery

Comment: @StevenMoseley how can i do this with jquery

Comment: A whole lot of HTML and CSS to display a huge amount of nothing in your jsfiddle

Answer (score 3):

If I am not misstaken, you are looking for something like this :

```
$('.sectiontableentry1').each(function(){
    if($(this).html().indexOf('recommended') != -1){
        $(this).hide()
    }
})
```

Since what you want is a little blurry to me, tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: Ran this in jsfiddle and it works. Forgive me if this is off topic but what does the "index not equal to -1" do? I just want to understand how it works.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon thanks sir for your help, to make it clearer My code get the html source code of remote page `<?php
    //Get the url
    $url = "http://lsh.streamhunter.eu/static/section35.html";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $html;
?>` then i want instead of echo $html as is, i want to remove or hide the rows that contain specific keyword thats it all i looking for to hear from you

Comment: `indexOf()` is getting the position of something in a string or an array. In this case, it get the position on "recommended" in the HTML. -1 mean that it fing no string "recommanded".

Answer (score 1):

There are no CSS selectors which select elements based on content. The only way to solve this problem without modifying the HTML is to use Javascript.

The best solution is to modify the HTML to include a 'recommended' class on table rows than add the CSS:

```
tr.recommended {display: none;}
```

Comment: I have no access to modify the html as its retrieved from remote server using file get contents

Comment: @MostafaBiomy Of course you can modify it's content if you're the one retrieving it.

Comment: @timss the source code is got automatically and it differs every minute and offcourse cant modify

Comment: @Mostafa Biomy You can do whatever You want with the code with You get. It's enought to use one of this functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php